# How to parse this specific JSON to String?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I've tried every solution I can to try to parse this JSON both with Newtonsoft.JSON and System.Web.Script.Serialization but I just get error by error no matter what method I use.

I'm trying to use the https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/stats?symbol=BTC-USDT API and I am trying to parse values from it so I can reference them later.

It's hard to show my code for this because I've tried so many different methods I don't exactly know what is wrong. I think it may be due to some weird formatting on the API itself but I'm not quite sure how I'd deal with that. How would I do this?

A code example: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/raw/uxomitoweb

Comment: Well, you can start by showing the code you have tried along with error messages that you get each time.

Comment: Doesn't look like any weird formatting to me. The JSON Viewer plugin in Notepad++ had no trouble with it.

Comment: A simple JSFiddle of JSON.parse works, so it appears the JSON is valid.

Comment: JSON in its native form is text AKA string.  So, nothing to parse.  Show *something* youve tried so we have some thing to work with.  And do add actual code and not a link to some site with some code on it.

Comment: Alright, I added some example code of what I've tried to do (which I've tried many variants of it from other help found on this site.)

I meant weird formatting by the two }} at the end might be confusing the deserializer? Not sure. I'm new to C# JSON parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. it was tested in Visual Studio and working properly

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");

var baseAddress =  @"https://api.kucoin.com";
var api = @"api/v1/market/stats?symbol=BTC-USDT";

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
            
var response = await client.GetAsync(api);

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
   var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
  }

}
```

classes

`````
    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
            public long Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public DataClass DataData { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DataClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public long Time { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("symbol")]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("buy")]
        public string Buy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sell")]
        public string Sell { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("changeRate")]
        public string ChangeRate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("changePrice")]
        public string ChangePrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("high")]
        public string High { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("low")]
        
        public long Low { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vol")]
        public string Vol { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("volValue")]
        public string VolValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("last")]
        public string Last { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("averagePrice")]
        public string AveragePrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("takerFeeRate")]
        public string TakerFeeRate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("makerFeeRate")]
        public string MakerFeeRate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("takerCoefficient")]
    
        public long TakerCoefficient { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("makerCoefficient")]
        
        public long MakerCoefficient { get; set; }
    }
````
`````

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. This is more complex then me as a beginner programmer would of been able to handle it seems.